# What are **options?

Tags: django

In the django docs how do I know what options I can provide certain classes? For example in the model field reference guide what can I pass to instantiate `PositiveSmallIntegerField()`?

```
class PositiveSmallIntegerField([**options])
```

This seems more explicit but it still has that strange `**options`

```
class ImageField(upload_to=None[, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, **options])
```

Is there somewhere I can find a reference on what these values are for? For example with the `ImageField` I did not know how it used `upload_to` until after I tried it. Apparently it creates the directory if it does not exist yet. What about a discussion on `MEDIA_URL` in relation to this? Where can I find that in the docs?

EDIT: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField) is the page I am referring to.

Comment: likely because it's just a standard python thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python

Comment: So my question was two fold I guess. Why the two ** (duplicate post) and where are the possible options and explanations for options in the docs (valid question?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of the page you have the [Field options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#field-options) common to all fields, you can use them there.

If you'll read the ImageField docs, you'll see the text:

> Inherits all attributes and methods from [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField), but also
>   validates that the uploaded object is a valid image.

Click the FileField link and you'll see the docs of those options.

Comment: So what's the difference between `class AutoField(**options)` and `class BigIntegerField([**options])` ?

Comment: Usually square brackets mean those are optional, see for example the signature for FileField:

`class FileField(upload_to=None[, max_length=100, **options])`

`upload_to` is mandatory, all others are optional.

Comment: Cool. I get it now. So is there anywhere in the documentation that says what those options do? For example the upload_to

Comment: Yeah, it's on the same page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to